What is the standard way to insert out-of-order elements in a list of a possibly smaller size?
What I have:
msg: list = []

expected behaviour:
msg.insert(2,"two")   # msg = [None, None, "two"]
msg.insert(10,"ten")  # msg = [None, None, "two", None, None, None, None, None, None, None, "ten"]

Current code:
def insert_into_list(orig_list: list, index: int, element: str)->None: # does not need to return the list
    if index >= len(orig_list): # sanity checks removed for MRE
        for _ in range(index - len(orig_list) + 1):
            orig_list.append(None)
    orig_list.insert(index, element)

Is there a better (or a more standard and possibly shorter than writing another method) way to do this?

You can replace the for-loop by orig_list.extend([None] * (index - len(orig_list) + 1)) but I'm not aware of a really elegant way to solve this.

It is inefficient to call list.insert repeatedly. Do you actually need all the items after the item being inserted to be moved backwards for each insert? You aren't showing that with your example.

um, not sure what you mean by move backwards. All it has to do is insert it into the right index regardless of the size. The only way that I know of doing that is extending the list upto the required index.

For example, if lst = [1, 2, 3], then lst.insert(1, 4) would make lst become [1, 4, 2, 3], where 2 and 3 have to be moved backwards to make way for the insertion, costing O(n) in time complexity as a result.

yup, that sounds about right. However, I'm wondering if I should enable an "allow overwrite" mode in the function

If you decide that the "allow overwrite" mode is far more typical for your use case, you should consider simply using a dict instead to store the index-value pairs for better efficiency, and converting the dict to a list only when you actually need it as a list.

Here's something that might fit your requirements.
code00.py:
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from typing import Any


def insert_fill(lst: list, index: int, element: Any, fill: Any = None):
    if index < len(lst):
        lst.insert(index, element)
        return
    lst += [fill] * (index - len(lst))
    lst.append(element)


def main(*argv):
    l = []
    insert_fill(l, 2, "two")
    insert_fill(l, 10, "ten")
    print(l)
    insert_fill(l, 1, "one")
    print(l)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(
        "Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(
            " ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
            64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32,
            sys.platform,
        )
    )
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)

Output:

(py_pc064_03.10_test0) [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackExchange/StackOverflow/q078325531]> python ./code00.py 
Python 3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0] 064bit on linux

[None, None, 'two', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'ten']
[None, 'one', None, 'two', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'ten']

Done.



I think this might be the shortest way of doing this.
def insert_into_list(orig_list: list, index: int, element: str) -> None:
    orig_list.extend([None] * (index - len(orig_list)))
    orig_list.insert(index, element)

In case of
msg: list = []
insert_into_list(msg, 2, "two")  # msg = [None, None, "two"]

It extends the original list with [None] * (2 - 0) = [None, None] and in case of
msg: list = [None, None, "two"]
insert_into_list(msg, 10, "ten")  # msg = [None, None, "two", None, None, None, None, None, None, None, "ten"]

It extends the original list with [None] * (10 - 3).
However, when the list is longer, than the index, it will multiply [None] with a negative number and result in an empty list, which will effectively only insert the element normally.
Hope that helped.
